# How to fire scroll (mousewheel) event with specific delta in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to fire scroll event in chrome with creating custom event by `document.createEvent` and I want to trigger all functions binded to scroll or mousewheel listeners (I'm not sure if it scrolls browser itself?). I catch event by `onmousewheel` listener but event object have `deltaX == 0 && deltaY == 0` when I used to specify their values:

```
document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function(e) {
  console.log(e.deltaX, e.deltaY, e.wheelDeltaX, e.wheelDeltaY)  // 0, 0, 0, 0
}

var e = document.createEvent('WheelEvent');
e.initMouseEvent('mousewheel', true, true, window, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, null);
e.wheelDeltaY = 120;
e.deltaY = 120;
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(e);
```

I'm not sure that I must use this type of event and this initaliztion type. So how can I specify event's delta values?

Comment: Beware: if your goal is to create a synthetic event to trigger the UI to scroll, that isn't possible because any event you create programmatically will have the `isTrusted: false` property which is equivalent to `preventDefault()` being called on your event, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events Instead, look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo as an (inferior) replacement.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, this is deprecated and you shouldn't use `initMouseEvent` at all.

What you should do is to create `WheelEvent` with `delta` params https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/WheelEvent and then dispatch it if you want to proceed with custom delta values or stuff like that.

Comment: Now I'm doing like this:  `var wheelEvent = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
      deltaX: 120
    });
    document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(wheelEvent);`

But `onmousewheel` and `onscroll` listeners didn't trigger

Comment: I got it, I needed to use another event, the final result looks like that:

`var wheelEvent = new WheelEvent(
  'mousewheel',  // scroll
  { deltaX: 120 }
);`

Big thanks to u, man!

Comment: My pleasure. If I helped, could I please ask you to upvote my answer? I'm trying to get to 50pts to be able to comment everywhere :)

Comment: I think I can't upvote because low reputation, but I clicked like button 100 over times I swear

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  console.log(e.deltaY)
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "scroll up";
  }
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "scroll down";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```